# Swift UI setting making rectangle square

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11, vstack

In SwiftUI, I have a VStack with a Rectangle inside. The rectangle automatically fills the parent VStack, which is great for the width, but I want to make the height equal to the width so it's square. How do I set the aspect ratio to 1:1 or set height = width?

```
VStack {
  Rectangle()
    .frame(height: ?? )  // I want to make the height equal to width so it's square
  Spacer()
```

}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's the [`.aspectRadio()` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/aspectratio(_:contentmode:)-6j7xz) that you need:

```
public func aspectRatio(_ aspectRatio: CGFloat? = nil,
                        contentMode: ContentMode) -> some View
```

> - Parameters:
>
>   - `aspectRatio`: The ratio of width to height to use for the resulting view. Use `nil` to maintain the current aspect ratio in the resulting view.
>   - `contentMode`: A flag that indicates whether this view fits or fills the parent context.
> - Return Value: A view that constrains this view’s dimensions to the aspect ratio of the given size using `contentMode` as its scaling algorithm.

If you give it an explicit `aspectRatio` of `1.0` you can be sure that it will retain its square shape:

```
VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
    Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you expect this

[image]

```
VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: I tried it this way too, without the 1.0, and this worked too.